# Soap Http post request gives IOException

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to send a Soap request to a server.

This is my java code:

```
    try {
        String xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.telenet.be/TelemeterService/\">\n" +
                "  <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                "    <ns1:RetrieveUsageRequest>\n" +
                "      <UserId>test</UserId>\n" +
                "      <Password>test</Password>\n" +
                "    </ns1:RetrieveUsageRequest>\n" +
                "  </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        URL myurl = new URL("https://t4t.services.telenet.be/TelemeterService?wsdl");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(xmldata.length()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\\\"utf-8\\\"\\r\\n");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());


        output.writeBytes(xmldata);

        output.close();

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());


        for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read())
            System.out.print((char) c);
        input.close();

        System.out.println("Resp Code:" + con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Resp Message:" + con.getResponseMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://t4t.services.telenet.be/TelemeterService?wsdl
```

I used this tool to be sure of my request: http://wsdlbrowser.com/soapclient?wsdl_url=https%3A%2F%2Ft4t.services.telenet.be%2FTelemeterService%3Fwsdl&function_name=retrieveUsage

I don't see whats wrong with my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I get an internal server error, the first thing I do (and maybe you did) is to check the application server log. For some unexpected reason(s) the server cannot be reached.
I don't see any problem to get the wsdl first to check if you can use the web service. It is an approach I do all the time.

Comment: I only checked the console output where the exception came. Do I need to check something else?

Comment: Sure. Can you execute the java application and at the same time do a tail -f of the application server log. What is returned ? Which application server ? Then you do https! Can you please read the 2 following documents ? To open an ssl connection you need to trust the server. Please have a look [Sending HTTPS requests from a Java program](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.iis.ia.restapi.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_restapi_sending_https_java.html) and [Java HttpsURLConnection Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/).

Comment: [Developing applications with the HTTP API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ia.restapi.doc/topics/c_api_https.html)

Comment: I'm doing this the same way. Only I use a DataOutputStream for my receive?

Comment: I believe you. Do you use the trust store ? You have to. What oses ? Client ? Server ? Can you open a terminal on both ?

Comment: I don't use the trust store. I can't open a terminal on the telenet server. I'm just a new developer that wanted to test the telenet API.

Comment: No trust store... No ssl. It is why I put some links to show you the way to open an ssl connection from a java application. Btw I can open a connection to your url from my browser... You should be able to do the same from your side.

Answer (score 0):

The **?wsdl** at the end of the url are for getting the wsdl, for example in a browser. Try removing it , making the endpoint URL **https://t4t.services.telenet.be/TelemeterService**.

Comment: What if you use the address described when opening the url in a browser:
**http://wlsCbemngdvip.prd.corp.telenet.be:9501/telemeter/TelemeterService**

Comment: Then I in chrome page not available